# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' [MailChimp Archive Embed]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mailchimp

I'm trying to load a script onto a React based site, and I'm running into issues because the script is a single document.write() line, which leads to the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an 
asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

Unfortunately, I can't change any of the script's code, so removing the document.write() and replacing it with something else isn't an option, at least not server side. My thinking was that I could retrieve the code first, rewrite it, and then run it with my corrections. What I've found is retrieving the code is also difficult.

The script source is using CORS, so my initial idea of using fetch to retrieve the code is out due to cross-origin not being allowed. In case you missed it, I don't have access to the server, so changing CORS is also not an option.

I'm currently trying to use callbacks to access the script's code, but I'm having issues with that too. What I'm wondering is if there is an easier way to access the code that a script has loaded in from its source, ideally before the browser attempts to run it.

**EDIT #1** : The script is coming from MailChimp. You pass in some info and it gives you back a document.write() line that it generates on its end. I hope this explains why I cannot change the script, and why I cannot change the CORS. I know a way to get around the CORS issue (setting up an API endpoint on my server that fetches the data from MailChimp will let me bypass CORS), but I'm looking for something more simple. I believe loading the script through an iframe and accessing the innerHTML might be the way to go, as suggested by @Jimmy Breck-McKye.

**EDIT #2** : @Jimmy Breck-McKye also suggested this might be an X/Y problem, and this may be the case. I need data that this script provides, but the script is trash because it uses document.write(). Reading data from a script can only be done through an ajax request, but that doesn't work with MailChimp because they've thrown CORS up around their lousy code. I've managed to get what I need by going around CORS, getting the script, and replacing document.write() with append(). Happy to share the code that got this working with anyone having the same issue, would love to hear a better solution.

Comment: How exactly are you hoping to make these scripts interoperate? Calling document.write implies the external script intends to render the whole page - which is going to be a problem even if you did find some way to intercept its contents. Maybe you could just open an iframe and let it operate in that?

Comment: No, if you cannot access it due to the SOP (and CORS not lifting it), then you also cannot access the source code in *any* way.

Comment: Why do you need this script, and why can't you change it? You should never run a script on your page that you don't have control over.

Comment: @Bergi is right. Running third party code like this would be asking for trouble. This feels like an X/Y problem

Comment: you should never run a script that uses document.write, because such script is from the 1990's! :D

Comment: Hi @david-c Ran into the same problem. Could you share the code that got it to work?